# 'Model' has no ForeignKey to 'auth. User'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a little problem with `Django-Admin`. So I have a model `UserProfile` which extends a regulear `User`. There are another models: `Language`, `Level` and `UserProfileLanguage` which is a through model.

```
class UserProfileLanguage(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('userprofile', 'language'),)
```

The problem is that I can't see attibute `languages` in `User` tab in `Django-Admin`:

```
class UserProfile(...
    ...
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='UserProfileLanguage')
```

So I've decided to put it explicitely into `User` tab so `admin.py` is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
admin.site.register(AdminContact)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'

# this does not work
class UserProfileLanguageLevelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileLanguage

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,UserProfileLanguageLevelInline, )


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(LanguageTuple)
admin.site.register(Language)
admin.site.register(Job)
admin.site.register(UserProfileLanguage)
```

CMD says:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp.admin.UserProfileLanguageLevelInline'>: (admin.
E202) 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp.UserProfileLanguage' has no ForeignKey to 'auth.
User'.
```

The problem is that `UserProfileLanguage` is connected with `UserProfile` and `UserProfile` with `User`. do you know what to do?

Comment: Are you certain Django is using your UserProfile model instead of the User model? You need to switch a flip here to let the UserProfile model take over as default User model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model